# The compilation of my Web.config section 'assemblies' cannot be read

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I created an application using asp.net 4, it work fine on my local server, but when I switched to an external server I have some strange problem with my web.config, I receive this error

```
[500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
]
```

.

It seems that inside the `<compilation>` section there are some problems. Just I have to say that when I remove the `<compilation>` section my application can be display and run, but without any access to the database.

web.config

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections></configSections>
  <appSettings />


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ImmoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ImmoModel.csdl|res://*/Model.ImmoModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.ImmoModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;User Id=XXXXX;database=XXXXX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>

    <globalization culture="auto:fr-FR" uiCulture="auto:fr-FR" />
    <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web1.siteMap" />
        <add name="web1" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/Web1.sitemap" />
        <add name="web" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/Web.sitemap" />
        <add name="web3" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/Web3.sitemap" />
        <add name="web4" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/Web4.sitemap" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>



    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->





    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->

    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="CaptchaImage.axd" verb="GET" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>

        <add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="MSCaptcha" namespace="MSCaptcha" />

      </controls>
    </pages>

  </system.web>


  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->


  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>




  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

</configuration>
```

Any idea what could be? I tried different way but still does not work.

Comment: Did you look at the event log of the server?

Comment: yes i have cheked the server's log . but it seems normal ..there is no  error tracking .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the following assemblies with proper version are installed in the GAC or reside inside the Bin folder of your project.

If any assembly that is not refered from bin is missing in GAC, you have to run the .net framework 4 again on the server.

If anything missing from bin , you have to make sure while including that assembly in your project you marked its Copy to.. property to true. or directly copy and paste that assembly to bin.

```
System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0
System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: i have copied all the Missing DLL to the bin folder , inside my project ! but i still having the same Error Page [ 500 Internal server error ].
should i ask the hosting company to check somthing ? or there's other suggestions ?

Comment: did you check all prerequisites are installed for asp.net 4?

Comment: afetr contacting the hosting company , i think all  all prerequisites DLL for .NET4 are installed ! but the problem persist ! 
in any case thanks for your answers .